# How to prevent addition of new workflow yml file to GithHub repository triggering redeployment to Azure App Service?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

**Background:**

I have one GitHub repo for a product which is deployed to multiple separate Azure web App Services. In the deployment centre (via the web portal) for each app service, I accepted the suggestion to create a workflow yml file, so that changes committed to the repo will trigger a redeployment. I believe this is achieved with GitHub Actions

This is useful to trigger redeployment when committing code changes to the main branch, however I am encountering an undesirable consequence of this setup:

- Let's say for example that I have to deploy the same app for a new client. If I create another new app service or add a new deployment slot and (via deployment centre) connect it to the same GitHub repo, a workflow yml file will be created in the repo
- The addition of this yml file to the repo triggers an app redeployment to all connected slots
- This forces a restart (and therefore a few minutes down time for warm-up) on all existing app services. Not good!

**Question:**

Is there some way that I can prevent the addition of new yml workflow files to the repo from triggering redeployment?

**What I tried:**

- Create a new App Service on Azure and connect it to a github repository to which several other App Services are also connected

**What I expected to happen:**

- The new App Service would create a workflow to trigger redeployment when code changes are pushed to the GitHub repo, and the other App Services would not be affected by this

**What actually resulted:**

- The new App Service created a workflow to trigger redeployment when code changes are pushed to the GitHub repo, but the addition of the workflow yml/yaml file to the GitHub repo triggered a redeployment to all connected app services, resulting in downtime

Comment: Glad to know the issue was resolved. If either of answers assists with your issue, you may consider accepting it. It will be helpful to other members who has the same issue. Thanks for the sharing.

Comment: Hi @Matt Smith, If the answers resolved your issue, you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will benefit the others with similar concerns. Appreciate the efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that my workflow .yml files are all added to the path .github/workflows/ by Azure, I was able to solve the problem by editing this section of the workflow .yml file from:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - thisbranch
  workflow_dispatch:
```

To:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - thisbranch
    paths-ignore:
      - '.github/workflows/**'
  workflow_dispatch:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [a path filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore):

> Use the paths filter when you want to include file path patterns or when you want to both include and exclude file path patterns. Use the paths-ignore filter when you only want to exclude file path patterns. You cannot use both the paths and paths-ignore filters for the same event in a workflow. If you want to both include and exclude path patterns for a single event, use the paths filter prefixed with the ! character to indicate which paths should be excluded.

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'app-service-1/**'
      - '.github/path-toworkflow-for-app-service-1'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on the right tracks. For my situation, I have multiple directories which should trigger the workflow, and only one (where Azure puts all of the workflow .yml files) which shouldn't. So, it seems ideal to use paths-ignore to ignore changes in that single directory ('.github/workflows/**'). I've added an answer to my question to explain what I did. If I understand right, your answer proposes the approach of specifying all of the paths which should trigger the workflow (which implicitly ignores all others?) I didn't end up trying this approach because it seems less robust

Comment: Yeah. Of course you know your issue better than me. I'm glad I was able to help you!